# How do I tell find to NOT sort found items alphabetically?

Tags: bash, find

Say I've got that directory structure:

```
|- xx.js
|- yy.js
|- zz.js
|- a/
   |- wv.js
   |- xv.js
```

When I do a `find -iname "*.js"` here, I get the following results:

```
a/wv.js
a/xv.js
./xx.js
./yy.js
./zz.js
```

How do I tell `find` that it shall not sort the found results by their name but by their depth, i.e. that way:

```
./xx.js
./yy.js
./zz.js
a/wv.js
a/xv.js
```

Comment: With my `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2` I get xx, a/*.js, zz, yy. But quoting [Dennis Williamson](http://serverfault.com/a/181805/200076): _You shouldn't rely on a particular output order from `find` and instead should use `sort` and other means to specifically control the order._

Comment: okay. I'm willing to use `sort` or anyone else. However: how?

Comment: @eckes, can you try `find . -printf "%d %p\n"|sort -n`

Comment: @Inian: add a `| cut -d " " -f 2`, make it an answer and I'll check it. Works just as I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @eckes: Cheers! np!